# Mongod illegal hardware instruction

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been having some problems with a query on mongodb and I managed to narrow it down to this script:

```
// db.broken.drop();
var obj = {routes: []}, 
    point = [-24.123, 24.213];

for(var i=0; i < 1696; i++) {
    obj.routes.push({points: [point]});
}
db.broken.insert(obj);
db.broken.find({"routes.points.1": {$exists: 1}});
```

That creates an object in the database like:

```
{
    routes: [
        {points: [[1, 2]]},
        {points: [[1, 2]]},
        {points: [[1, 2]]},
        // ...
    ]
 }
```

I figured that if the routes nested obj size is over 1695, mongod will crash on me with on that query:

```
[1] 32887 illegal hardware instruction mongod -vvv
```

Thats on Yosemite, with mongodb 2.2, 2.6 and I even tried on 2.7, just in case. It also happens on linux with ubuntu.

Has anyone stumbled on anything like this before? Am I doing anything terribly wrong or this is a bug?

Comment: May be this issue is related to an unresolved open issue, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7251. Something to do with CPU incompatibility. Couldn't replicate the issue on my machine though.

Comment: You got me to test on another machine and there, with a new mongodb, it did not crash. I checked the version and saw that it was 2.6.6. My servers use 2.6.5 and also local, on my machine. So i checked the changelog for 2.6.6 and found this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15899

Comment: Even i tested it on v2.6.5, which works fine. so i am still skeptical about the version issue here.

Comment: Thats really odd. Just got home from work and tested again. I had 2.6.4_1 on this osx machine. Ran the script and it broke. Upgraded to 2.6.6 and its working. Switched to 2.6.5 and bam, broken again. What OS are you using? I'm Kinda curious of whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running mongodb 2.6.4 and I believe that [this is the bug](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15899) causing the aforementioned problem. Upgrading to mongodb 2.6.6 seems to fix it.